# How to .cumprod() two different pd.Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Question

- From the example below, can I calculate the **`cum_series_c`**, based on  **`cum_series_a`** and **`cum_series_b`**?

### Example

```py
import pandas as pd

# I don't have these two pd.Series (a and b) in my pocket.
# In other words, I cannot make use of these two pd.Series.
series_a = pd.Series([1,1.03,1.02,0.98,0.99])
series_b = pd.Series([1,0.98,0.95,1.05,1.07])

# I am given these two cumprod series, cum_series_a and cum_series_b
# I know what these varibles look like. 
cum_series_a = series_a.cumprod()
cum_series_b = series_b.cumprod()

cum_series_a
>> 0    1.000000
   1    1.030000
   2    1.050600
   3    1.029588
   4    1.019292 

cum_series_b
>> 0    1.000000
   1    0.980000
   2    0.931000
   3    0.977550
   4    1.045979

#######################################################################################
# What I want to calculate is the cum_series_c based on cum_series_a and cum_series_b #
#######################################################################################
series_c = pd.concat([series_a, series_b[1:]]) 
cum_series_c = series_c.cumprod()

### Attention, please!
# I don't need the first element of the series_b, because it is 1.
# So it would repeat the same number 1.019292 two times, if I didn't delete it.

cum_series_c
>>> 0    1.000000
    1    1.030000
    2    1.050600
    3    1.029588
    4    1.019292
    1    0.998906
    2    0.948961
    3    0.996409
    4    1.066158
```

- To put my question in other words, is it possible to calculate the **`cum_series_c`** without knowing the `series_a` and `series_b` but knowing only **`cum_series_a`** and **`cum_series_b`**?
- What would be a code like to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can by factor all `cum_series_b` with the last element of `cum_series_a`

```
cum_series_c = cum_series_a.append(cum_series_b * cum_series_a.values[-1], ignore_index = True)
```